# youtube embeded video error NO ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN

Tags: youtube-api

As you can see here https://mohamed-hassan.com/samples/project24/ ,
if you open the console you will see this error

> (ZYLR4KocS2Q?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&mute=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0:1 Failed to load https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id: Redirect from 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' to 'data:text;charset=utf-8,' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.youtube.com' is therefore not allowed access.)

I just embedded video from youtube using `iframe` tag and I added at the top of the index file `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` but still get this error.

Here is a screenshot
[image]

Comment: See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present) for further info about your error. Also you can try to check [this post](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/291/how-to-solve-the-client-side-access-control-allow-origin-request-error-with-your-own-symfony-3-api) for the step by step solution.For YouTube API reference, open [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to add `&origin=https://yourdomain.com` to your iframe src, this value allows YouTube to add the proper headers to its response.

Comment: how to write that code with iframe ? sorry im new in programming tho.

Comment: Fixed for me! @FebriTahta so for example, if your youtube link is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AXaLzjv3O0` and your website is `https://example.com`, for the youtube link of your video, put this entire thing: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AXaLzjv3O0&origin=https://example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Error fix with this code:

```
<iframe class="lazy" allowfullscreen="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/youtube_video_id?origin=https://yourdomain.com&showinfo=0&video-id=youtube_video_id&enablejsapi=1&widgetid=1&color=white&modestbranding=1&rel=0" data-title="video_title" title="video_title" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Note: setting the `color` parameter to white will disable the `modestbranding` option. 
: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters